# How to change the icon position in FloatingActionButton extended

Tags: dart, flutter

The icon on FloatingActionButton extended is on left, how can i put the icon on right? after the text

[image]

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(   
            onPressed: (){},
            label: Text("Next",),
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,
            ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `FloatingActionButton`, but instead you can configure a **RaisedButton** to look very similar.
Just use it same as you would do it with FloatingActionButton.

```
floatingActionButton: RaisedButton(
        child:  Container(
          height: 50.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                   Text('Next', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),),
                   const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                   Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 30.0, color: Colors.white,),
                   const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          ]),
        ),
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Do somenthing');
        },

      )
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any direct way to do that.
But as a workaround, you could just pass a `Row` widget (Which contains a `Text` and `Icon` widgets) to `label` parameter.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: () {},
    label: Row(
      children: <Widget>[Text("Proceed"), Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)],
    ),
    icon: Container(),
  ),
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice way to do it ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Material library (M2 in this case. I know M3 exists but I'm still catching up)

you can set `app:iconGravity` to `end` or `textEnd` to achieve the desired effect you want

https://m2.material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#extended-fabs

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/continue_text"
        app:icon="@drawable/my_drawable"
        app:iconGravity="end" />
```